# How To Fix Vertical And Horizontal Layout Of Combo Box In Qt Designer?

Tags: qt-designer

I have two combo boxes that are in different horizontal layouts in qt designer as Shown in below Picture.
I want to layout them vertically too.
I used spacers but didn't work when resizing.

[image]

Comment: Hi Reza, please post the essential piece of code and *I used spacers but didn't work* statement is not gonna help the potential helpers. Please explain what didn't work.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj   there is no Code(I use property editor). and when I use spacer and allign two combo boxes vertically if I set central widget to layout in a grid and then run the app. the combo boxes are not alligned vertically

Comment: @rezamoslemi then share your .ui

Comment: @rezamoslemi To layout both horizontally and vertically, you must set a grid layout ***on the group-box***. The spacers aren't needed. Once the grid-layout has been set, you can drag/resize the combo-boxes to align them as required.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thankyou, helped me much!